# Which figure is this a statue of?

Tags: ancient-greece, identification, art, classical-greece

In [Ocean's 12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean%27s_Twelve), towards the end of the movie in the famous scene where Night Fox is dodging the laser field to steal the (fake) coronation egg at the museum, we see this statue in the foreground.

[image]

My question is, what is this statue or rather or who is this a statue of? It seems like a famous classical Greek figure, maybe even a mythological figure. The figure is beautifully haunting and has been bugging me ever since I first saw it in the movie.

The clip is in HD [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzAKSbtYBMU) with the statue showing up for a few seconds starting at 1:06.

This is not a movie question but rather a question regarding a piece of art of classical antiquity. That's why I am posting it here hoping the history buffs can help me instead of the Stack Exchange Movies Beta.

Thanks.

Comment: This shows 3 statues, not 1. Are you asking about the middle one?

Comment: Should this question be rephrased to refer to Ocean's Eleven so that it can come up on search engines?

Comment: Btw, have you checked imdb's trivia section?

Comment: This can be a Roman statue too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably a statue of [Antinous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antinous). (Or Hermes)

In fact it is probably this one here (notice the object behind his leg):  [image]

It is located in the Capitoline musuem in Rome.  It is supposed to be Antinous in the shape of the Greek god Hermes.  See more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitoline_Antinous).  (There is a debate on whether the statue is in fact a Roman copy of a Greek statue of Hermes)

Comment: Why do you think so? Do you have any evidence?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace No concrete evidence but the curly hair, long nose and brooding downward gaze is typical of an Antinous statue. There are also more statues of him than any other real life Roman or Greek.

Comment: In fact the curly hair is according to the article *non* typical of Antinous. But I think you found the statue whose copy is in the movie, so +1!

Comment: Well Antinous is usually depicted with curly hair, just not as curly as on that particular statue!  The object (tree trunk) which I thought was a Hermes giveaway is in fact a regular component of most large marbles statues, sculpted to support the main statue.

Answer (score 6):

The museum in the movie is "Galleria d'Arte di Roma", [a museum that doesn't actually exist.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0349903/trivia?item=tr0684772) The figure itself is a rather generic good-looking curly haired figure of renaissance Italy, and is in looks fairly similar to for example [Michalengalo's David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_%28Michelangelo%29), although it's clearly not that statue, nor a copy of it.

So the answer is most likely: It's not really supposed to be a statue of anyone, but just a generic Hollywood "Italian statue". It may be that this statue is a replica of some actual statue, but it's hard to say, especially since it's hard to say which statue it actually is in the wide-shots.

Comment: David is exactly what I thought too. It is clearly not *The* David though, as that statue is way larger (17 feet tall) than the one in this shot.

Comment: The head is the wrong angle as well.

Comment: @LennartRegebro [This article](http://articles.latimes.com/2004/dec/12/entertainment/ca-how12_) has more detail about the creation of the museum set for Ocean's Twelve. Apparently some of them were replicas, but it doesn't specify which and what they were replicas of.